# Whitelisting in XSD

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, schema

I have to create and XSD where i have to allow/forbidd certain attribute combinations.

In the Code Down there, the first "thing" should be allowed.

The second "thing" is supposed to be forbidden, because the it doesnt match my template(but it could be anything, it's not specifically booooforbidden) but i also have to allow more than one possible attribute value.

In the third thing its forbidden, because the title is not allowed.

Now the super tricky part: in the 4th "thing" the title is forbidden, but its an exception. Normally everything with that title gets banned, but that one is supposed to be allowed.
Does anyone have a clue on how to do this? I'd be so incredibly greatfull, thank you

```
   <thing title="jack_theRipper">
    <something value1="imallowed" value2="boooo"/>
   </thing>
   <thing title="jack_theRipper">
    <something value1="imallowed" value2="booooforbidden"/>
   </thing>
   <thing title="jack_theRipperforbidden">
     <something value1="imtext" value2="boooo"/>
   </thing>
   <thing title="jack_theRipperforbidden">
     <something value1="imtextallowed" value2="boooo"/>
   </thing>
```

blacklisting won't work, because it could be anything that gets inserted as a value, and i just have to allow some combinations

Answer (score 0):

**Individual XSD Component Values**

Whitelisting (the specification of *allowed* values) of individual component values is the normal method of expressing data type constraints in XSD.  For strings, enumerations are often used.

Blacklisting (the specification of *not-allowed values*) capabilities of individual values are limited in XSD 1.0 but can be done via assertions in XSD 1.1.

**Combinations of XSD Component Values**

Whitelisting or blacklisting combinations of component values requires XSD 1.1's assertions.